# How to use sourcemap with evaluation TypeScript from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'll show the code first (node 10.15.3):

```
var ts = require("typescript");
require('source-map-support').install({
   environment: 'node',
   hookRequire: true
})
var content = "let a = 0;\n\nb = b * a";

var compilerOptions = { 
   module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
   inlineSourceMap: true 
};

var res1 = ts.transpileModule(content, {
  compilerOptions: compilerOptions,
  moduleName: "myModule2"
});
console.log(res1);
console.log('-------')
console.log(content)
console.log('-------')
console.log(res1.outputText)
console.log('-------')
eval(res1.outputText)
```

As a result of executing this code I want to have a traceback related to a given content variable (Error in line 3), but I constantly receive an error in line 2 - which is line of error in compiled version of code.

Here is an output

```
{ outputText:
   'var a = 0;\nb = b * a;\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoibW9kdWxlLmpzIiwic291cmNlUm9vdCI6IiIsInNvdXJjZXMiOlsibW9kdWxlLnRzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBLElBQUksQ0FBQyxHQUFHLENBQUMsQ0FBQztBQUVWLENBQUMsR0FBRyxDQUFDLEdBQUcsQ0FBQyxDQUFBIn0=',
  diagnostics: [],
  sourceMapText: undefined }
-------
let a = 0;

b = b * a
-------
var a = 0;
b = b * a;
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoibW9kdWxlLmpzIiwic291cmNlUm9vdCI6IiIsInNvdXJjZXMiOlsibW9kdWxlLnRzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBLElBQUksQ0FBQyxHQUFHLENBQUMsQ0FBQztBQUVWLENBQUMsR0FBRyxDQUFDLEdBQUcsQ0FBQyxDQUFBIn0=
-------
SS: /root/ts-eval/exal.js undefined
SS: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js undefined
SS: internal/bootstrap/node.js undefined
ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/root/ts-eval/exal.js:24:1), <anonymous>:2:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/ts-eval/exal.js:24:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: In typescript you actually have to declare the variable, it won't work like as in javascript.

Comment: @VikashSingh The problem the OP is facing is how to get a stack trace that reports the error with a correct line number. The `ReferenceError` is caused *on purpose* so as to get a stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

You are using inline source maps, and the [documentation](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support) for `source-map-support` states:

> To support files with inline source maps, the `hookRequire` options can be specified, which will monitor all source files for inline source maps.

You've set `hookRequire` to true. However, the passage I've quoted indicates `source-map-support` relies on hooking into `require` to detect inline source maps, and so if your code executes without passing through `require` then its source map won't be detected and `source-map-support` won't be able to fix the stack trace. Indeed if I replace your `eval` call with this code:

```
fs.writeFileSync("myModule2.js", res1.outputText);

require("./myModule2");
```

I get a stack trace like this, with the correct line number:

```
ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/t4/module.ts:3:1)
[...]
```

The file name is `module.ts` because the option `fileName` has not been specified to `ts.transpileModule`. You could set it to `myModule2.ts` for consistency with `moduleName`.

Also, if you change your compiler options to also inline the sources, like this:

```
var compilerOptions = {
  module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
  inlineSourceMap: true,
  inlineSources: true,
};
```

You get a bit of a nicer stack trace. With `compilerOptions` like shown above and `fileName` as I suggested earlier, the trace is:

```
/tmp/t4/myModule2.ts:3
b = b * a
^
ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/t4/myModule2.ts:3:1)
```

You can see before the `ReferenceError` a reference to the line of code that caused the problem.

---

The approach above is the simplest one that results in `source-map-support` fixing source references. Here is another, more complicated approach, which **does not require saving any files to disk** but requires customizing how `source-map-support` gets source code from a source file path. The comments in the source indicate what the new part do.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const ts = require("typescript");
const vm = require("vm");
const path = require("path");

// This establishes a mapping between sourcePaths and the actual source.
const sourcePathToSource = Object.create(null);

require("source-map-support").install({
  environment: "node",
  // Pass to source-map-support a custom function for retreiving sources
  // from source paths. This runs after source-map-support's default logic,
  // only if that logic fails to find the requested source.
  retrieveFile: (sourcePath) => sourcePathToSource[sourcePath],
});


const content = "let a = 0;\n\nb = b * a";

const compilerOptions = {
  module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
  sourceMap: true,
  inlineSources: true,
};

// The path that the ts module would have.
const tsPath = path.resolve("myModule2.ts");

const res1 = ts.transpileModule(content, {
  compilerOptions: compilerOptions,
  fileName: tsPath,
  moduleName: "myModule2"
});
console.log(res1);
console.log("-------");
console.log(content);
console.log("-------");
console.log(res1.outputText);
console.log("-------");

// The path that the compiled module would have.
const jsPath = path.resolve("myModule2.js");

// Establish the relationship between the path and the source.
sourcePathToSource[jsPath] = res1.outputText;
// Ditto for the source map file.
sourcePathToSource[path.resolve("myModule2.js.map")] = res1.sourceMapText;

vm.runInThisContext(res1.outputText, {
  filename: jsPath,
});
```

Running the code above results in this output:

```
/tmp/t4/myModule2.js:2
b = b * a;
^

ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at /tmp/t4/myModule2.ts:3:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:123:20)
[...]
```

The source line numbers in the stack trace are modified by `source-map-support` to point to the right place but the source reference at the very beginning is not modified. The problem is with the regular expression that `source-map-support` uses. The regular expression requires the source file reference to be in parentheses (like `(vm.js:123:20)`). I've tried transforming the exception before `source-map-support` gets to it so that it fits the regular expression but `source-map-support` does not see the transformation.

Comment: the idea is to have an exception from eval

Comment: @Oduvan I've added another way to do it that does not require writing files to disk, and uses `vm.runInThisContext` to execute the code. That's as close to `exec` as I can get it. Unfortunately, `exec` does not allow setting a file name for the code that executes in it, so there's nothing for `source-map-support` to work with.